# Is it a bad idea to hold references to ArcObjects inside business classes?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine

According to best practices is it a bad idea to cache features and geometries inside business objects? If it is bad, what is the alternative way?

References to features may be replaced with their Ids, but what about geometries?

Answer (score 7):

In general this shouldn't be a problem but there are some objects in the ArcObjects library that you want to be very careful about managing their lifetimes so that you don't tie up critical resources or keep locks on database tables for extended periods.

Among lots of other good info, in [this thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/4298-What-s-Up-with-ComReleaser-Is-it-really-working) James MacKay lists some of the types of objects you should take special care with:

> - Cursors
> - Datasets, i.e. tables, feature classes, feature datasets, rel. classes (but excluding name objects)
> - Workspaces (inc. versions, if you're connecting to multiple versions of an enterprise GDB at once)
> - Rows, features and attributed relationships
> - Row buffers and feature buffers

If you are using .NET then you should be aware that it is a [garbage-collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) environment, and COM objects are not necessarily released as soon as they go out of scope, but can linger on until application shutdown unless you explicitly release them, call [`GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (not recommended), or the GC finally decides to clean them up on its own. For more info see [Releasing COM references](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Releasing_COM_references/0001000004tm000000/) in the ArcObjects SDK help.

I think storing row IDs instead of rows themselves is a good idea, but you should be okay storing geometries that you create as long as memory consumption is not a problem. As @Ragi mentions below, if the geometries are coming from a recycling feature cursor, be sure to use [`IFeature.ShapeCopy`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ShapeCopy_Property/002500000331000000/) to create a clone of the feature's geometry. I am also assuming your business objects will not need to be [serializable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), which could complicate matters.

I have stored [`IFeatureClass`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002qs000000) references (which keep connections open to their source workspaces) in business objects and implemented logic to specifically release them as soon as they were no longer needed (see [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), if you are using .NET, for the MS-recommended dispose pattern, and [IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About) for a better understanding).

Comment: Thanks the answer. I'm aware of managing objects lifetime in ArcObjects, and always try to release unused references :) I worry about threading issues in ArcObjects, may be caching references in BO is bad idea, as they may reference some kind of shared resource. Because I faced some kind of non repeated errors in ArcGis with geometry and TopologicalOperator - incorrect buffer results, sudden hangs.

Comment: The ITopologicalOperator is its own can of worms -- perhaps ask a separate question about the issues you are having with it.

Comment: If you want to hold FeatureClasses or other objects, it should be OK. Just remember you are keeping them alive. For geometries, it depends where you got them from. For recycling cursors, you should never hold a reference to them - that's the COM contract for that interface. If you do want to keep them, then clone them (since that would be your copy). Holding ids of features is acceptable, too, since if you are editing, ArcObjects will keep the internal caches in-sync for you.

Comment: I suppose keeping a reference to features within a classextension would violate [this rule](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Init_Method/0025000000t8000000/).

Comment: @blah238: I wonder what your Dispose() method looks like.. if it contains Marshal.ReleaseComObject, it most likely does not have the desired effect since you cannot be sure how many times to call this method. If it contains Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject, you risk releasing a RCW which some other managed code is still referencing, which can be fine only in very specific scenarios (e.g. a standalone application, or when you are about to delete the feature class). In other words from my point of view, the dispose pattern makes little sense on IFeatureClass references except few cases.

Comment: It calls ReleaseComObject, and this happens once for each business object that gets disposed. This decrements the reference count to a given feature class wrapper and when the reference count is reduced to 0 the COM object is disposed. You are correct that FinalReleaseComObject would result in disconnected RCWs in some cases, since more than one business object could reference the same feature class.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall yes, you are right that you also want to avoid any kind of circular references; the FC holds an internal reference to the class extension and you want to avoid your class extension holding a reference to the class. related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15834/why-do-arcmap-exe-processes-stay-open-after-i-close-arcmap

Comment: @blah238: Actually CLR calls IUnknown.AddRef at most once, and maintains its own counter on the RCW. This counter gets increased whenever a call crosses .NET/COM boundary. So, ReleaseComObject returns the internal RCW's reference count, not the COM object's reference count. This means that when you call ReleaseComObject in your Dispose method, it is very likely that it has no effect, since there could be loads of cross-environment calls and you can never know how many.

Comment: The side effect of this behavior is also this: calling FinalReleaseComObject (or ReleaseComObject multiple times until it returns 0) does not mean that the COM object is disposed since there may be another references to it from unmanaged code. It merely releases the RCW.

Comment: See http://jpassing.com/2009/03/26/rcw-reference-counting-rules-com-reference-counting-rules/

Comment: I did some testing and watched the shared lock files in a file geodatabase get deleted when ReleaseComObject runs (and returns 0). If I comment out this line the locks remain until I shutdown ArcMap. So for me it's behaving as I expect it to.

Comment: If it works for you in your particular scenario.. all is well. I already hinted few scenarios when it will NOT work. Also, my opinion is that understanding what happens under the covers never hurts. Not that it matters, but I believe your answer is incorrect.

Comment: The bottom line is, you can only reliably release COM objects which you create yourself (in geodatabase development most often these are cursors, geodatabase enumerations etc.). Workspaces and by extension feature class references are most often not the case since you are given those references from the outside (the environment such as ArcMap). I've seen way too many bugs which stem from not understanding the underlying COM interop mechanisms in .NET properly.

Answer (score 3):

You do not describe in detail what exactly are your *business objects*. It is a largely overloaded term and many people tend imagine very different things.

Given that your business objects are the same as domain objects in the sense of traditional domain-driven design, I am gonna suggest the exact opposite of blah238's answer (even though it contains a lot of valuable information) - do NOT keep references to *geodatabase objects* in your business objects.

The rationale behind this suggestion might not be applicable for the simplest applications, but please bear the following points in mind:

1. Most geodatabase objects, be it a workspace or an individual row, are a effectively a handle to geodatabase resource. In case of SDE or direct connect, it translates to a network connection to SDE/database. For local geodatabases, it might result in a lock on a filesystem resources. Now, in a reasonably layered design, you most certainly would NOT keep a reference to a network connection (or an abstraction like the [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)) in your business objects. You are doing exactly that when holding onto geodatabase objects.
2. As stated in other answers and comments, references can be held only onto rows produced by a non-recycling cursors. For one, switching from a recycling cursor to non-recycling has performance implications. But more importantly, changing the underyling data fetching mechanism solely for the purpose of your domain breaks the principles of loose-coupling. Whenever you can capture the data in your domain object instance, you can do so for both recycling and non-recycling cursors equally provided you do not keep the reference to the underyling row.
3. Related to 2., one has to ask what is the real purpose of your business objects? Do they keep any state themselves, or do they rely solely on the data contained in the kept IRow instance? Seems like your business objects are just some functionality (methods containing business logic) operating on an IRow instance. This, again, comes down to your design and what exactly you consider to be business objects, but a crafty mapping between IRow fields and your business object properties at the time of reading them from the geodatabase will give you a much cleaner domain model and get rid of the IRow dependency.
4. Whenever you couple your domain model classes with a geodatabase-related objects, your code almost automatically becomes untestable with unit testing. That is, unless you are willing to undertake mocking ArcObjects, which is virtually crazy. See [How to unit test ArcObjects with Mocking](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-to-unit-test-arcobjects-with-mocking) for more details.
5. There are also few rules to follow when holding onto IRow references which further make your life harder. When editing, you must discard and refetch IRow references on several occasions, e.g. when starting an edit session or upon undo/redo. See the bottom of [IWorkspaceEdit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m5v000000) documentation for a more thorough discussion.
6. Similarly to 5., in a multi-user geodabase environment, references to tables, feature classes etc. need to be refreshed when a geodatabase version changes.

Now, again, validity of all of these points largely depends on your particular scenario and needs. Holding onto ArcObjects is obviously not prohibited and I do that myself on occasions. You just need to be aware of the implications, of which there are many. As I tried to hint, some of these are technically purely ArcObjects-related, some are more of a higher-level software design nature.

Comment: +1, these are some good points especially regarding loose coupling, but in some cases performance trumps design ideals. In my case I found it much faster to keep a strong reference to feature classes because the cost of connecting to and disconnecting from feature classes frequently was too severe. I could have probably written a data access layer to manage the connections to feature classes independent of the business objects but this was a very small ArcMap extension, not a standalone application. I do not think there is any hard and fast rule so it's good to have multiple perspectives!

Comment: For now I cache both geometry & features references in my BO. BO themselves hold feature`s field valued in private fields and expose them through public properties. They also have some domain logic and preform CRUD operations on features.

Comment: So I want to follow best practices in software development during refactoring this nightmare(I`m on a long way of studying).So to achieve loose coupling it  is better to break application into layers and separate ArcGis API through DAL and utility classes and use some interchangeable storage of GIS specific data in domain model(like WKB)?

Comment: You can keep geometries as references to IGeometry instances as long as you get them through a non-recycling cursor or using IGeometry.ShapeCopy. Other than that, yes, for larger applications I would introduce dedicated business layer. For smaller extensions, is is most likely an overkill.

Comment: I recommend reading "Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software" by Eric Evans, it will give you an interesting perspective on design. With that, it will also give you new interesting challenges and things to think about on how to do good design with ArcObjects :-)